# Why mysql select query to select data for a particular user between to dates is not showing proper data?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using the query

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from tablename 
where name='$name' 
and date between '$newDate' and '$newDate1'");
```

Suppose, I am giving username xyz and want to see data from 01st may 2014 to 02nd may 2014, it is returning data from 01st may to 02nd may along with 01st apr to 02nd apr too. As I have started adding data from 1st of apr. Same case is for all dates. It is showing data of particular date along with the data of other months having the same date. How to solve it. Need your help badly? Plz do reply my question! Thanx in advance?

Comment: how ur dates are stored in mysql and what is the exact input values for `$newDate` and `$newDate1`

Comment: My dates are stored in dd/mm/yyyy format and I have declared date as varchar 100. The exact input values for $newDate= '01/05/14' and for $newDate1='02/05/14'.

Comment: This is the problem that you get when you store dates as strings.  I would suggest:  `alter table tablename modify column date date` to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but, if I do the same then my all dates may changed to 0000-00-00. What you say?

Answer (score 0):

You are using varchar(100) for date datatype. use DATE(datatype) then check. Because date function check the date in between Y/m/d format.

Comment: Friend, If I change the date type from varchar to DATE then my all dates may change to 0000-00-00. So, I can not afford this because I have a huge collection of data in my db. Also, I want to mention that the query worked fine but, suddenly from tomorrow the same problem raised.

Comment: Seriously: bad database creation. Store your dates in Date fields, and you can manipulate them either inside the database or outside a lot more easily.

Comment: I know friend. I have done this as I am new to the same. So, apologize from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad design, you should store date as date or datetime.
Now varchar is not considered as date and hence the comparison fails and it will be 
treated as string comparison not date.

This is one of the way you can achieve what you are trying

```
select 
name,
date_format(str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') from test
where 
date_format(str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
between 
date_format(str_to_date('01/05/14','%d/%m/%y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
AND 
date_format(str_to_date('02/05/14','%d/%m/%y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99f11f/4)

Comment: Abhik, After using this code the condition is not satisfying. This code is definitely helping me by changing the data type of date but, after using this my query is reeturning null value. Any Help bro?

Comment: please post the tables and data in http://sqlfiddle.com and provide the input values for which the filtering needs to be done.